# Drag and Drop Android Webpage element - Appium 4.2.0

Tags: c#, android, selenium, drag-and-drop, appium

I am having a great deal of trouble dragging and dropping an element on a web page on an Android tablet.
The code I am using is this:

```
        IWebElement dragFrom = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(dragElement));
        IWebElement dragTo = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(dropElement));
        Point fromPoint = dragFrom.Location;
        Point toPoint = dragTo.Location;

            ((AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>)driver).Context = "NATIVE_APP";


        new TouchAction((AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>)driver).
            LongPress(fromPoint.X, fromPoint.Y).
            Wait(3000).
            MoveTo(toPoint.X, toPoint.Y).
            Release().Perform();

        ((AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>)driver).Context = "CHROMIUM";
```

However when I use this the very top of the browser gets tapped, either the browser tab or maybe it pulls down slightly from the top slide menu on the device.
I've looked at the X and Y to and from points and they are not the top left of the screen (X 740, Y 50)

Originally I just used Actions but I get some crazy error message with it "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy. Proxy error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: 501 - "unimplemented command: "

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.DragAndDrop(
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(dragElement)),
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(dropElement)))
            .Release()
            .Build().Perform();
```

I also used the below code, but now an error tells me that Swipe does not exist

```
                TouchAction action = new TouchAction((IPerformsTouchActions)driver);
            action.Press(startX, startY).Wait(1000).MoveTo(endX, endY).Release().Perform();
            ((AndroidDriver<IWebElement>)driver).Swipe(startX, startY, endX, endY, 100);
```

Does anyone have a solid way of dragging and dropping an element on a webpage when using an Android device? Or know what I've done wrong in the above code?

It appears that when appium taps the screen, its not taking into account the size of the browser header, so when it taps Y 24 for example, its going by the total screen size, and not the web page screen size. So it taps 24 pixels down from the top of the phone screen, and not from the top of the web page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get this working. After updating the Appium desktop programme to 1.19 I could get Actions working again.
So I used this

```
            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

        
            actions.DragAndDrop(
                driver.FindElement(By.XPath(dragElement)),
                driver.FindElement(By.XPath(dropElement)))
                .Release()
                .Build().Perform();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            actions = null;
```